# How to get length of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to get value of below array, I have used `.length` function but it returns no response, below is my array

```
{
"0":["Paypal Priority Placement:","39.9291958","-79.4478858","8"],
"1":["Government Hospital","69.1167545","-105.0637655","5"],
"2":["Other service","51.4611608","-2.5811462","3"],
"3":["Medanta Hospital","49.809962","-97.1344368","2"],
"4":["Amit's Clinic canada","45.487635","-73.586142","1"]
}
```

Comment: That's not an array, though.

Comment: if you do your `.length` on your object it will not work.
`{} -> object
[] -> Array`
be more precise and search before to post